# Terraform state file locked and stuck can't complete

Tags: terraform

while running terraform plan i did a CTRL C on a windows computer  and now when i try to run terraform plan again i get

> Error: Error loading state: Failed to read state file: The state file could not be read: read terraform.tfstate: The process cannot access the file because another process has locked a portion of the file.

I tried

> terraform force-unlock  id

but that gives me

> Local state cannot be unlocked by another process

I am kind of stuck and cannot move forward

Much appreciated if someone can please assist.

Regards,
KKR

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you save the state file in s3 or local? If it is from remote, try to delete that state file first and retry. If it is local process, you will need to kill the process and delete the state file from your local folder `.terraform/terraform.tfstate`

Comment: Note to self - the AWS tf state locks are in the dynamo db table(s) - see https://discuss.hashicorp.com/t/s3-backend-state-lock-wont-release/21367/4

Comment: I had deleted the tflock file in remote and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

i had to kill the terraform process and then resume

Answer (score 0):

I faced this issue when trying to run a `Terraform Init` and `Terraform Plan` from two different instances of AzureCLI task (a similar AWS task in your case). Move all the terraform commands to a single instance of the task and that should fix the issue.